# What does this expression mean in nginx rewrite module?

Tags: regex, nginx

I am encouted a regular in Nginx rewrite config:

```
location /main {
    root   /home/hldev/hldata/frontend/credit-system-frontend/dist;
    rewrite ^/(?!js|css).*$ /main/index.html break;
}
```

the `^` match the start of the url,the `$` match the end of the url,the `*` present one or more,but what the whole expression meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^/(?!js|css).*$` means: for each string starting (`^`) with a slash (`/`) that is not followed by "js" or "css" (`(?!js|css)`), consider all the characters (`.*`) until the end (`$`).

Basically, all the relative paths that do not start with "js" or "css".